# How to use input() as a name for object in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, input

I'm new to python and I've been trying new things.
I made this class:

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self,school,gpa,age):
        self.school=school;
        self.gpa=gpa;
        self.age=age; 
    def stu_info(self):
        print("School: ",self.school)
        print("GPA:", self.gpa)
        print("Age:",self.age)
```

and then I typed this code to create objects of the class.
The problem is taht I wish to use the input() function to enter the name of the object. Here is the code I wrote (which does not work).

```
School=input("What is your school's name? \n")
Gpa=input("What is GPA? \n")
Age=input("How old are you? \n")
StudentName=input("Name: ")
StudentName=Student(School,Gpa,Age)
print("Saved")
```

You can see that my problem is in these lines:

```
Name=input("Name: ")
Name=Student(School,Gpa,Age)
```

An object with the name (StudentName) is always created and I can get the information by using StudentName.stu_info().

Do you have any ideas on how I can use the value of StudentName as a name of an object?

thank you in advance

Comment: Have you learned about dictionaries yet? This is basically what they're for.

Comment: I have a used dictionaries before but how could I use it in here?

Comment: `d = {}; name = input(); d[name] = Student(School,Gpa,Age);`. Then you just lookup in `d`.

Comment: When I lookup `d` I get this: `{'Mazen': <__main__.Student at 0x2919c75a550>}` and if I use `Mazen.stu_info()` I get `name 'Mazen' is not defined`

Comment: `d["Mazen"].stu_info()`. Don't try to create arbitrary variables. It'll make your life difficult later. Store the "variables" in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
name = input("Name: ")
locals()[name] = Student(School,Gpa,Age)
```

*But don't do that*. Instead use a dictionary:

```
students = {}
students[name] = Student(School,Gpa,Age)
```

Comment: I used the first method and worked just fine for me.. why shouldn't I use it? And I reall didn't get the dictionary method..

Comment: Because it's a hack. `locals` is a mutable dictionary of available variable names. When you access `some_variable`, it's looked up from `locals`. You're polluting locals by putting all your students in there. Less polluting will be to use a dictionary